# Change text "email"

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

Where can I change the text "email" to "email to friend"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To translate new text you can add text and its translation in module language csv file like this :

```
'Email','Email To Friend'
```

**File Path**

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/i18n/en_US.csv

Then run CLI command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Is there any translate interface available in Magento Admin to translate each "text" to "another langauge text"?

e.g. Drupal Translate Interface (Built-in)

Comment: try this https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/translate-inline.html

Comment: translate-inline only available for Enterprise Edition?

Comment: nop that is support for all version.

Comment: The problem with this method is that when you click on a link for sending to Email label on a form also becomes 'Email to Friend' instead of just Email, also for the field where you should enter your own email, which is not fine

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Email under below file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/mailto.phtml

Copy the mailto.phtml to below location:

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/mailto.phtml

And then change the text from "Email" to "Email to Friend".